# asp net force browser to reload jquery file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I am working with mvc C# and I have two different pages that use different Jquery versions.

This happens because my layout always calls a Jquery bundle

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") //calls a 1.7 version I think
```

But one specific page (lets name it: SpecialPage) calls another file that is only used in that specific page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/test landing/js/jquery2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

I would like to make the browser forget the jquery2.2.4.min.js whenever the user is not in the SpecialPage?, since this issue is making other components of my web page to break.

Thanks

Comment: Since only one page which uses higher jQuery version than included in bundle, why not just use `jQuery.noConflict()` only for that page instead of removing bundled one?

Comment: thank you very much, I am new with front end. How would I use that? Can you give me an answer so I can vote it please?